# Why am I getting a "this2" is undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, scope, this

I assume this has something to do with binding `this` somewhere, and the fact that I am trying to iterate over an object. In this code I can see that the responses are valid, I just get an error for the `this.setState` line: `_this2.setState is not a function.`

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('MatchesScreen: ', Object.keys(this.props))
    Object.keys(this.props.profile.profile.matches).map(function(username, keyIndex) {
      console.log('match', username)
      url = 'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/profile?username=' + username
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({isLoading: false})
        this.props.updateMatches({matches: responseJson})
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      })
    })
  }
```

By comparison, this code works totally fine, I assume because there is no looping going on?

```
componentDidMount() {

    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
        bypassCache: false
    }).then(user => {
      username = 'username=' + user.username
      this.setState({username: user.username})
      url = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/profile?' + username
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
          age: responseJson.basic_info.age.toString(),
          height: responseJson.basic_info.height,
          promptQuestion: responseJson.prompt_question,
        })
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('EditProfileScreen: error getting user: ', err))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a function defined by `function` statement, `this` won't refer to an upper function scope, because in JavaScript each function creates it's own scope when it's defined. If you use a function defined by with an arrow function notation it will keep the scope.

You can read more about function scopes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you can read more about arrow function notation.

Comment: thanks for the response. so do i need to change the format of the mapping then? to use an arrow?

Comment: @MattTakao did my recommendation help you?

Comment: Yes, thanks very much! Arrow function solved the issue.